# Javascript callback function - how do the parameters get populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I understand that callbacks are functions you pass as a parameter into another function, such as in the following simple example:

```
function operation(a,b, callback) {
    return callback(a,b);
}

function add(a,b) {
    return a+b;   
}

function multiply(a,b) {
    return a*b;   
}

console.log(operation(5,4,add)); // 9
console.log(operation(5,4,multiply)); // 20
```

What confuses me greatly about callback functions is when they are used in chained function calls, such as the following:

```
// Angular example
$http.get(...).then(function(req,res) {
    // some actions here
});

// JQuery example
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
    // some actions here
});
```

In both examples, how are the parameters in the anonymous function populated? Does this in any way relate to the callback logic I gave in the operation function example I gave or is this some other concept entirely?

My best guess for the angular example is that the http promise returns an array object [req,res] and the function parameters are pulled from the array in sequential order.

What is of specific interest to me is how I could define my own chained function call in this style. How can I define something like:

```
myObject.performAction(function(param1, param2, param3) {
    // do stuff
});
```

If someone could give an example like that, it would be amazingly instructive.

Comment: I guess you will have to bind values to it. Eg: function (a,b,c){}(param1,param2,param3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters are passed to callback function by the calling code - same as in your example `return callback(a,b);`

```
var myObject = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  performAction: function(callback) {
    callback(this.a, this.b, this.c);
  }
};

myObject.performAction(function(param1, param2, param3) {
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: In the case of $http.get(...), does the returned object have two attributes (req and res) and a function called then, which is a callback on those two attributes? I know I'm probably oversimplifying a bit but is that the general idea?

Comment: of course, the signature of the function you pass as a callback must match the signature expected by the code that accepts it

Comment: $http returns a promise object defined here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q. the function you define for `.then` will be called with the response object as the first param when the promise is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Based on Igor's answer, I came up with the following to mock the $http.get(...).then() syntax:

```
var myObject = {
    transform: function (value) {
        // Perform some logic based on the value parameter
        var squared = value*value;
        var cubic = value*value*value;
        return {
            a: squared,
            b: cubic,
            action: function(callback) {
              callback(this.a, this.b);   
            }       
        }
    }
};

myObject.transform(12).action(function(a,b) {
    console.log(a+b); // 1872
});
```

The idea is that in the transform function, you perform some logic on the value parameter so that `a` and `b` are derived from some calculations instead of just being hardcoded values. That way the callback in `action` becomes a lot more meaningful.

This effectively abstracts the parameters `a` and `b` from the user in the anonymous function call in `action`. This is why these parameters have to be documented for the API call to `myObject.transform.action`.